# How do I resolve the linker error when I try to use CIFilter in my iOS (iPhone) app?

Tags: ios, linker

I get the following link error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CameraViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CameraViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I already have included the QuartzCore.framework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html